# Name of graph of euclidean norm function?

Tags: real-analysis, euclidean-geometry, terminology

Does the graph of the euclidean norm function $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R},\,x\mapsto \sqrt{x_1^2+\cdots x_n^2}$ have a special name? I'm particularly interested in the case $n=2$.

Comment: It is a cone, or more precisely, a rotational conic surface.

Comment: umm. $z = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$  is a cone, note $z \geq 0.$  Also note, when $y=0,$ that $z =|x|$